# How "reject" instancing a class

Tags: java, c++

For example,

```
public class Test {
    Test() {
    if(xxx)//do some check here
        //reject instancing class test.
    }
}
```

I think I can throw a exception to reject it, is there any other way?
I am not sure what's the effect of instancing been rejected, but I think a natural way is:

```
Test test = new Test();//return null here indicating instancing rejected.
```

I expect java and C++ all should have this "reject" feature.

Comment: ¤ C++ is flexible enough to allow you to *easily define* such a feature, e.g. as a macro `NOXNEW` (short for "no exception `new`") as [I show here](http://codepad.org/0jADRP8O). I presume the same is true for Java, but implemented in some different way. However, note by doing this -- returning nullpointer -- you're throwing away any exception information, which is in some cases very undesirable. However, presumably in such cases you simply would not do this. But it's worth being very aware of. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Note: in the above answer I'm using a macro just to pass a variable number arguments, because Visual C++ 10.0 (the current version) does not yet support variadic templates, and as far as I know they will not be there in Visual C++ 11 either. For full standard C++11 the macro would not be necessary. For that matter, with some library support, e.g. as presented on my main blog, it isn't strictly necessary for C++03 either, although it makes for simpler and more clean usage. Cheers,

Comment: Also, now that you got me thinking about it, I think that code can be greatly simplified. It's the simplification that's work. And when you done it you wonder how on Earth the original code could be so stupidly complex, but I'm just giving it to you straight, with minimal work. :-)

Comment: Why do you actually want a null pointer? Failing a constructor is not absurd (and an important part of RAII), but is usually an exceptional case that, well, deserves exceptions instead of a silent "return nullptr" fallthrough. I wonder if your real problem isn't bad design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature built into the language, but you have two standard ways of implementing it:

- The first one is throwing an exception. You hinted at it in your post. The callers would need to expect this exception, and be prepared to handle it.
- The second one is a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). It may return null if it fails to instantiate your class for whatever reason. Your callers need to be ready to handle null returns from your factory method.

Choosing between the two options is not easy. The guideline is that if rejecting instantiation is an *exceptional situation*, e.g. a programming or a configuration error, then go the exception route. If rejections are going to happen routinely, e.g. because some resource is *temporarily* unavailable, then go the factory method route. Of course there are exceptions to these rules, so use your best judgement.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to return null you could get use of [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern). E.g. instead of `Test test = new Test();` you could write `Test test = TestFactory.CreateTest();`, and implement all the checks you need in `TestFactory.CreateTest`.

`new Test()` always returns a non-null instance of `Test` (at least in Java).

Answer (score 2):

You can't return null from a constructor, but you can (as you suggest) throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should throw an exception if you are unable to create an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I can throw a exception to reject it

Yes indeed, throwing an exception from the constructor will destroy all sub-objects (if using inheritance) and members already initialized.  This is the preferred way of aborting the construction of an object.

> is there any other way?

The only other way is to initialize to a dummy state and require to client code to check that the constructor ran successfully using a special-purpose method.  Since clients are prone to forget such calls, I really don't recommend this approach.

As for this "solution":

```
Test test = new Test();//return null here indicating instancing rejected.
```

There's no way to coerce `new` to return a null pointer from inside your constructor, so this can't work.  You could simulate this using another method such as:

```
class Test
{
    Test (...); // constructor that receives prepared arguments.
public:
     static Test * create (...)
     {
         // prepare arguments...
         if (successful) {
             return new Test(prepared_arguments);
         }
         return 0;
     }
};
```

And use this in your code as:

```
Test * test = Test::create(...);
if (!test) {
     // handle error.
}
```

But you can still forget to check for a null pointer.

The preferred method is to throw an exception.  It's simpler, always effective and requires less typing.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, You do not neccessarily have a pointer to return, consider:

```
Test t; // run the constructor
```

Thus, using exceptions or the factory pattern are the only ways to reject instanciation.